# Как сделать так, чтобы нажатии на кнопку СРАЗУ?

Tags: java, android, button

Как сделать так, чтобы нажатии на кнопку СРАЗУ(не отпуская кнопку) запускался процесс, который нужно для этой кнопки?(извините за первый , неправильно заданный вопрос)

Comment: Не очень ясна задача. Возможно вам нужен onLongClickListener?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, скорее всего нужен евент не на **клик**, который подразумевает нажатие и отпускание, а просто нажатие. В js - что-то типа `mousedown` или `touchstart`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вам нужен onTouchListener:

```
button.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 return false;
}
  }))
```

Comment: Большое спасибо!!!

Answer (score 0):

Для этого нужно повесить на кнопку setOnLongClickListener().
Вот как можно это сделать:

```
YOUR_BUTTON.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        // Тут выполняем нужные действия

        return true;
    }
});
```